# Activation of new Registered site fails on multisite

Tags: multisite, user-registration, activation, multisite-user-management

I recently installed multisite to my main site. I put a registration link at the top of my page.  I tried registering a new site and user.  The steps were straight forward with username, email, and then on the next page the URL creation.

An email was successfully sent to the correct email registration with the link

http://123456789abc.atmydevice.com/wp-activate.php?key=3713068298425278

to follow to activate the new site.

However, this link can not be found and when I check my sites on the admin page for multisite there is no new site for 123456789abc.xxx.com

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: What permissions does your database user have?

Comment: I think I have to add: Did you add the wildcard *.domain.ext as a DNS record? How do I do this?

Comment: That has to be done in your virtual hosts file of your web server.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed the right configuration in your hosts file.

Assuming you are using Apache on a Linux server and vi editor, open this file:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
```

Since you have installed Multsite as subdomains, adjust your directives to include these:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example"
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that ServerAlias can help you with wildcard entries.

After making the changes, make sure you restart Apache with this command:

```
sudo restart apache2
```

Try running your activation link again and let us know if it works.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled multisite, and went through the steps again, now knowing all the correct steps to follow.  So the second time around I got everything to work just fine.